# C++ class member variables reassignment

Tags: c++, function, class, object, methods

---

### This program

---

My object `Class` has a member variable `balance` which is set during initialization and manipulated through the method `augment` which is given a double to add to `balance`.

The `Class` object is nested in an array in the `Class2` object which has just the array of `Class` objects as its members. The `Class2` object has a method to access a `Class` object called `getClass` and a method to manipulate a `Class` object called `setObject`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Class {
    double balance;
public:
    Class();
    Class(double setBalance);
    void augment(double amount);
    double getBalance();
};

class Class2 {
    Class object2[50];
public:
    Class getClass(int index){
        return object2[index];
    };
    void setObject(int index, double balance) {
        Class temp(balance);
        object2[index]=temp;
    };
};

Class::Class() {
    balance = 0;
}

Class::Class(double setBalance){
    balance=setBalance;
};

void Class::augment(double amount) {
    balance+=amount;
};

double Class::getBalance() {
    return balance;
};

int main() {
    Class2 object;
    object.setObject(5, 546);
    cout << object.getClass(5).getBalance();
    object.getClass(5).augment(546);
    cout << object.getClass(5).getBalance();
    return 0;
}
```

---

### The problem

---

If you follow the procedure in `main`, I'm trying to initialize a `Class` object with a `balance` and manipulate the `balance` through the `augment` method. It looks like this code should work and if the object was accessed directly and not nested in `Class2` it does work, but that's not an option. I think it has to do with the way the `Class` object is returned in `Class2` but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You're using implicit-copy operations, so your code is creating copies of your `Class` instance, modifying its state (i.e. `balance`) and then discarding the result. Instead use pointers or references to a single `Class` instance.

Comment: Specifically you should probably have a `Class& getClass(int);` and `const Class& getClass(int) const;`

Comment: @Dai That's **always** the problem... but when I make changes to try to return the Class as a reference I get lots of **red**.

Comment: @cltco What would the `const Class& getClass(int) const;` do for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "red"? If you're getting compiler error messages please post them rather than being vague and nonspecific.

Comment: @henryaaron it would give you the ability to get `const` references to the elements when you have a `const Class2`. Without it, you would not be able to access the elements from a `const` context.

Comment: @Dai Had to do with the way I was returning them. Mistake

Comment: @clcto Won't be necessary. The `Class&` worked well. Thank you

Comment: @henryaaron it may not be necessary now, but in the future you will probably want a way to get read-only access to the elements if you have a read-only `Class2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return reference to an object in the array

```
Class & getClass(int index){
    return object2[index];
};
```

You could define the subscript operator in Class2 to access elements of the array.

Also take into account that it is a bad idea to use class names Class and Class2.

Comment: It was just a sample program to reproduce the problem... I do not have classes named *Class* and *Class2*

Comment: @henryaaron You could use qualifier const with some functions of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm a little late, but my two cents would be to overload the assignment operator and create a copy constructor, just to ensure your class is copied and assigned correctly. It may be a little old fashioned, but I'm a fan of following the rule of three. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class Class1 {
    private:
        double balance;

    public:
        Class1() : balance(0) { };

        Class1(double setBalance) :
            balance(setBalance) { }

        // create a copy constructor
        Class1(const Class1& src) : balance(src.balance) { }

        // destructor that does nothing
        ~Class1() { }

        void augment(double amount) {
            balance += amount;
        }

        double getBalance() { return(balance); }

        // overload the assignment operator for your class
        Class1& operator=(const Class1 &src) {
            balance = src.balance;
            // make sure to return *this which returns a reference to the
            // current class object (in this case, the current Class1)
            return(*this);
        }
};

class Class2 {
    private:
        Class1 object2[50];

    public:
        Class2 () = default;

        Class1 getClass(unsigned index) {
            assert(index < 50);
            return(object2[index]);
        }

        void setObject(int index, double balance) {
            assert(index < 50);
            object2[index] = Class1(balance);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Class2 object;
    object.setObject(5, 546);
    std::cout << object.getClass(5).getBalance() << std::endl;
}
```